# WPF WebBrowser Controlar ventanas emergentes

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo un proyecto en WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation).
En un WebBrowser dentro de un Window muestro una página web que contiene unos enlaces que disparan ventanas emergentes, entonces:

1) ¿Cómo habilitar por defecto la opción de permitir todas las ventanas emergentes?

2) ¿ Cómo mostrar las ventanas emergentes en un nuevo Window, no en una ventana exterta de Internet Explorer?

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo de lo que llevas ya para ayudarte

Comment: De antemano gracias. No he iniciado ya que no tengo idea de como hacerlo.